# How to add multiple IDs to a discord.js check?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, nodes

I am trying to make a simple script that checks if the users ID is the one in the script.

But I can't seem to figure it out.

I hope you guys can help me.

```
if(message.author.id !== '272412823148298240') return message.channel.send("you do not have permissions")
```

So i want to add another 2 IDs to it so the other 2 people can also use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them to an array and check if the current author's ID is in that array:

```js
const authorized = [
    "272412823148298240",
    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
];

if (!authorized.includes(message.author.id)){
    return message.channel.send("you do not have permissions");
}
```

Comment: you don't need to put `String`, you can just say `.includes(message.author.id)`, since the id is already a string

Comment: @MrMythical Yes you're right. I made a habit of explicitly using `String()`, `Number()` and `Boolean()` for the Types I need (I use JSDoc a lot). But I edited the post, thanks!